# Is the induced map on $K$-points surjective?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $X$ and $Y$ be schemes locally of finite type over an algebraically closed field $K$, and suppose $Y$ is etale.

If $f:X \to Y$ is a surjective morphism of schemes over $K$, then is the induced map on $K$-points $X(K)\to Y(K)$ also surjective?

My attempt: $Y$ has the discrete topology (etale over an algebraically closed field). The (open) fiber of any $y\in Y$ must contain a $K$-point since the set of $K$-points of $f^{-1}(y)$ is very dense, hence not empty.

Comment: Are you sure you want absolutely no assumptions besides $Y$ etale over an algebraically closed field and $f$ surjective?

Comment: @KReiser Sorry, I forgot the "locally of finite type" assumption. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your attempt is basically correct, but could justify a few more things. Here's an explanation which is maybe a little over-justified.

As $X\to\operatorname{Spec} k$ is locally of finite type, $X\to Y$ is locally of finite type ([ref](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01T8)), so any base change of $X\to Y$ is again locally of finite type ([ref](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01T4)). Since the schemes etale over a field $k$ are $\coprod_{i\in I} \operatorname{Spec} K_i$ for $k\to K_i$ finite separable ([ref](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02GL)), we have that $Y=\coprod_{i\in I} \operatorname{Spec} k$ as $k$ is algebraically closed. As surjectivity is preserved under base change ([ref](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262104/why-is-surjectivity-stable-under-base-change)), the base change $X\times_Y \operatorname{Spec} k \to \operatorname{Spec} k$ is a surjective morphism locally of finite type, so $X\times_Y \operatorname{Spec} k$ is a nonempty scheme locally of finite type over an algebraically closed field $k$ and therefore it has a $k$-point: on a nonempty affine open, we're looking at the spectrum of a nonzero finitely-generated $k$-algebra, which has a maximal ideal, and by Zariski's lemma the residue field at this closed point is a finite extension of $k$ and therefore $k$ itself. Therefore there is a $k$-point of $X\times_Y \operatorname{Spec} k$, which induces a $k$-point of $X$ mapping down to our chosen $k$-point $\operatorname{Spec} k \subset Y$ by the map $X\times_Y \operatorname{Spec} k \to X$. Thus the map $X(k)\to Y(k)$ is surjective.

Comment: Thank you for this justification. I just am not sure if "the base change $X \times_Y Spec k$ is a surjective morphism" should be "$X \times_Y Spec k \to Spec k$."

Comment: @mathfan24 yep, just mistyped.

Comment: So the $k$-points of $X\times_Y Spec k$ are exactly the $k$-points of $X$?

Comment: @mathfan24 no, but the $k$-points of $X$ over the chosen point $\operatorname{Spec} k \subset Y$ are the $k$-points of $X\times_Y \operatorname{Spec} k$, as you can see from the fiber product diagram defining $X\times_Y \operatorname{Spec} k$. I've added a few words to the answer.

Comment: Thank you for clearing this up!